# Buttons that are initially invisible

Tags: c#, winforms, visible

I am making a 'window form app' on c# app. I have couple of 
buttons and text boxes. **What I want is that when I run
app for the first time some buttons and text boxes are invisible.**
And After I click a certain button those buttons and text boxes
become visible.

At the moment when I run app every thing (buttons and textboxes) is 
visible on the form initially. I can make them visible and invisible
after pressing a button or so but initially every thing is visible.

Comment: can you post your codes?

Comment: Set the [`Control.Visible`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.visible.aspx) property to `false` in the constructor of the form or in the properties box in the design view.

Comment: Or maybe this is not your codes. And you are asking how the program works. Just set `btn.Visible = true;`

Comment: here is a great Tutorial you need to read `user1903439` http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/csharp/csharp.html

Comment: thanks for the answers and the tutorial link

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every [Button](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.button%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) class has a [Visible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.visible%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) property, just set it to `true` or `false`, to show the button or hide it accordingly.

- first from PropertyGrid set [Visible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.visible%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) property to `false` (for those buttons that should not be visible on startup)
- handle click on others
- on click of one of them (based on your app logic) make =>

(example)

```
btnMyInvisibleButton.Visible = true;
```

Comment: In the Windows Forms designer window for example...

Answer (score 4):

Set the `Visible` property to false on the designer for each control you want to hide to begin with.

Simply set this to true in the code later on (for example on a button press event), when you want them to become visible again.

MSDN reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.visible.aspx

Answer (score 3):

All you need to do is to make them invisible in the Form Designer by setting their Visible property to False.

NOTE: They will *still* be visible in the designer if you do that - but they will not be visible at run time.